# Can't update query Android

Tags: android

This is no error but I can't seem to update my TABLE ACTIVITIES.

I can't find what's wrong with these statements. There's no problem with the values.

```
goal_id = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("goalid"));
int i=0;
Activities act = new Activities(goal_id,activityname.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(days.getText().toString()),i,false);
dbhandler.updateActivty(act);
```

//Updating an activity

```
 public int updateActivty(Activities act) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhandler.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ACTIVITY_NAME, act.getActivityName());
        values.put(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DAYS, act.getDays());
        values.put(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_NO_OF_TASKS, act.getNoOfTasks());
        values.put(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_COMPLETE, act.getComplete());

        // updating row
        return db.update(MyDBHandler.TABLE_ACTIVITIES, values, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(act.getId()) });
    }
```

Comment: Why update? Also you usually pass data to an adapter which he accesses the part of udpating data.

Comment: well, im passing off new values.

Comment: What is the return value of db.update?

Answer (score 0):

updateActivty method is never called . use Event bus to send data activity to activity.

Comment: db.update method return s value if update is success  then it return long value > 0 if not success it return <= 0 . at first log the value if not sucrss then check database is already created , column name , table name , and the id

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would work a bit more and do the following:

Try to see if data is in the database by searching for values for that id:

```
   public static Cursor find(SQLiteDatabase db, String uid) {
     Tables table = Tables.YourTable;//it can be an enum or something static that contain/gives access to all of your columns. Hopefully it is clear.
     return db.query(table.getTableName(), 
     getColumnNames(table), 
     COLUMN_NAME_ID + " =?", 
     new String[]{uid}, null, null, null);
  }
```

Next:

You create an adapter that can be accessible form everywhere:

```
MyAdapter implements IMyAdapter
{
    @Override
    public boolean insert(IRow row){ 
        boolean success = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            openIfDatabaseIsClosned();//here you get the writeable database and store it somewhere(I do it for multiple databases).
            try {
                row.insert(getDB());
                success = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(IRow row) {
        boolean success = false;
        synchronized (lock) {
            openDatabaseIfClosed();
            try {
                row.update(getDatabase());
                success = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Your error message:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

Your row will look like that:

```
interface IRow
{
   void insert(SqliteDatabase db);
   void update(SqliteDatabase db);
   void delete(SqliteDatabase db);
   void find(SqliteDatabase db);
}
```

Next you implement something like

```
MyRow implements IRow
{
  public(to be accessed from outside upon creation) static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final string COLUMN_VALUE = "value";
  //here you do your implementation, with columns and stuff like that.
  //Of course you need to take care of the creation of tables
  update(SqliteDatabase db){//TODO}
  insert(SqliteDatabase db){//TODO}
  delete(SqliteDatabase db){//TODO}
  //for update/delete/insert you can here implement the values assemble method.
}
```

As you could notice, the YourTable is in this case something called MyColumn and contains some columns that will usually be part of MyRow so that when you update your values you can access the columns.
Basically you just have to create the tables and you are done.
This works/worked for me on 3-4 projects, without any errors. 
I prefer this way due to the fact that a lot of things can go wrong when passing strings, etc.